# Would there be radiation if there is no relativity?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation

I am learning special relativity. And for the equations derived (e.g. retarded potential, dipole radiation, radiation damping etc.), it seems to me that if there is no relativity (c becomes infinity), there will be no radiation, as c always appears in the denominators of the equations. Is my understanding correct? I appreciate any insights. Thanks!

Comment: The revolutionary concept introduced in special relativity was that the speed of light is the same for all observers, not that the speed of light is finite. That the speed of light is finite was known well before 1905 (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light#History)).

Answer (score -1):

Postulating infinite light speed leads to a vastly different universe with little if anything recognizable.  See https://www.quora.com/What-would-the-observable-universe-look-like-if-light-speed-was-infinite

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) If you provide a link in an answer, please add a short summary of its content/its most important statements so that even once the link is dead, your answer is still of value to readers.